# how to log only object properties from MONGODB in console

Tags: mongodb, console.log, objectid

I want to log only objects (say courses object) from MongoDB but when I write

```
  > "console.log(courses)"
```

it logs unnecessary things too from database (like strict mode, selected and so on) which are not included in my object properties, so what can be done to log only objects properties (i.e id,name)

I have tried to write code like `console.log(courses._doc)` but it didn't work

```
 model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: [Object],
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5d207fc27c9ecf2f688d1f5f,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      session: null,
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': [Object]
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: { _id: 5d207fc27c9ecf2f688d1f5f, name: 'Node Course' },
    '$init': true
  },
```

I expect the output to be only

```
 _doc:{_id:5d207fc27c9ecf2f688d1f5f,name:'Node Course' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're using mongoose. if this is the case then you can use `courses.toObject()` based on this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6067).

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue, you need to loop over your result like so:

```
courses.forEach(course => {
    console.log(course.toObject());
});
```